# Programatically set the AdMob id String

Tags: android, xml, admob

I have several apps I am working on which use common `XML` interface elements.  One of these elements loads `AdMob`.  I can duplicate the element in each project and put the unique `ID` for each app in the duplicated `XML` file but I am wondering if there is some way to programatically set the `I`D string from the application while keeping the `XML` and not having to duplicate it in each project.

Something akin to:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AdView aView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.admob);
    aView.<method goes here that sets ads:adUnitId>
```

I know that instead of instantiating `AdMob` from the `XML`, I can do that programatically, or that I can copy `main.xml` to each project and modify the `ID`s there, rather than using the one in my library.  But I would be happier with a solution similar to my sample code above which lets me keep the `AdMob` code in `main.xml` and doesn't make me update `main.xml` in n places when it changes.

I have been unable to find a class reference or complete description for the deliverables that come with `AdMob`, and auto complete does not show me any method which would seem to fit this need.  If anybody would point me to a place which does have a good description of the `AdMob` classes, that would be a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set an empty place holder View (ListView for this example) for the AdView in your XML, and then add the AdView programmatically in Java, something like:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.adplaceholder);

//create the AdView (replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with the admob ID of your choice)
AdView av = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID);
lv.addView(av);//add the AdView to your layout

AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 5):

I did following

1. In your library project add in the string.xml an element with value "" that represent the adUnitId.

   ```
   <string name="ad_unit_id"></string>`
   ```
2. In your layout insert the adView with

   ```
   ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"`
   ```
3. In your other project(s) add in the string.xml the same element with the current adunitId

   ```
   <string name="ad_unit_id">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>`
   ```

Enjoy :)

Comment: I did the same and it worked for my first project, but the second didn't. I don't know why

Comment: It always raises warning "Failure getting entry... in package ..."