# Android - How to Dynamically set AdMob advertiser ID or ad size?

Tags: android, admob

Example code provided in https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner works fine for me using a given advertiser ID and ad size in xml file. But it is very important for me to be able to set advertiser ID and banner size based on certain parameters.

I considered these two but they did not work for me ->

[Programatically set the AdMob id String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088174/programatically-set-the-admob-id-string)
and

[How to specify adUnitId programmatically for AdMob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766257/how-to-specify-adunitid-programmatically-for-admob)

When I try to implement second one I get errors when I try to link java file to xml file. How they should be linked?

Comment: please post your code. @ARIPOVULA

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
frameLayout.addView(mAdView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```